# How to use Space in column name with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have used in my java *DAO* class which contains Space in between LANG PREF

```
 @Column(name = "LANG PREF")
  private String langprefid;
```

Once my java class runs, I am getting

`org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`

Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

Comment: You should rather change the name of the column itself. It's just bad practice to have spaces in column names.

Answer (score 18):

### Manually escaping the reserved keywords

If you're using Hibernate native API, then you can escape them using backticks:

```
@Column(name = "`LANG PREF`")
```

If you are using JPA, you can escape with double quotes:

```
@Column(name = "\"LANG PREF\"")
```

### Automatically escaping reserved keywords

If you want to automatically scape reserved keywords, you can set to `true` the Hibernate-specific [`hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`](https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/) configuration property:

```
<property
    name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers"
    value=true"
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change your code to

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
@Column(name = "LANG_PREF")
private String langprefid;
```